# jhipster is generating different front end code

Tags: jhipster

I am working on a project for around 2 months. I was using jhipster 6.1.2 and blueprint is jhipster-vuejs 1.1.0
I accidentally updated jhipster to 6.4.5 and then I could not import jdl file. It was showing an error. So I again install jhipster 6.1.2 and able to import jdl file. But jhipster is generating angular code. It's replacing my vuejs code into angular js code. What should I do?

Comment: Yeah. 
  "blueprints": [
      {
        "name": "generator-jhipster-vuejs",
        "version": "1.1.0"
      }
    ] 
and
 "generator-jhipster-vuejs": {
    "jhipsterVersion": "6.1.2",
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "baseName": "jobportal",
    "useSass": true,
    "clientPackageManager": "npm",
    "clientFramework": "vue",
    "clientTheme": "none",
    "clientThemeVariant": ""
  }

Comment: Do you want to see my .yo-rc.json file?

Comment: When I used --force command it automatically adds angularX. I deleted that part and tried again but again it generates angularX code.

"blueprints": [
      {
        "name": "generator-jhipster-vuejs",
        "version": "1.1.0"
      }
    ],
    "useSass": true,
    "clientFramework": "angularX",
    "clientTheme": "none"

Comment: Can you try to replace blueprints with blueprint? We changed it from singular to plural as in earlier versions only one blueprint was supported.

Comment: I replaced blueprints with blueprint and the following error shown blueprint.startsWith is not a function. Any other idea?

Comment: Sorry for being a little unclear. Can you try replacing blurprints with    "blueprint": "generator-jhipster-vuejs" so also replacing the array with a simple string please?

Comment: After using "blueprint": "generator-jhipster-vuejs"  it shows "info Using blueprint generator-jhipster-vuejs for entity-client subgenerator" but also shows this error 
events.js:187
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined

My Jhipster version is 6.1.2

Comment: Can you check if in the local node folder of you application the jhipster version is really 6.1.2?

Comment: Yeah I checked that. It's "version": "6.1.2" and 
"_from": "generator-jhipster@6.1.2",
  "_id": "generator-jhipster@6.1.2",

Comment: I just found that JHipster 6.1.2 requires"jhipster-core": "4.0.2" but generator-jhipster-vuejs blueprint requires "jhipster-core": "3.6.8". Is it causing the problem?
When I first created This project JHipster version was 6.2.0 and the blueprint version was 1.1.0. I tried with both 6.1.2 and 6.2.0 but nothing seems working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you give the --blueprint switch when triggering jdl import? If not does it help somehow? The jhipster core version might be a problem.